# Access 2010 Runtime Error 2185

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

Hi I have an application created in Access 2007, it's front-end and back-end is split. I am trying to open the database using Access 2010 runtime, however the application crashes when I change selected item of a combo box.

I receive the following error:

**"Execution of this application has stopped due to a run-time error. The application can't continue and will be shut down."**

After researching the problem, a few people mentioned running the compact and repair, and found that fixed their problem, however it made no difference to mine.

However, I found most people to come back and say put some error logging in place. So I have done that, and when running on 2010 runtime, a receive a pop up message saying the following:

**Error number: 2185, You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus.**

However when running in Access 2007, there is no error and the code works fine.

This is the code I have been using:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If Not ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
ComboBox1.Dropdown
End If
End Sub
```

My question is, why would this suddenly become an issue running on 2010 runtime, when there is no error in Access 2007?

Comment: I had a few odd problems switching my test databases to 2010, but decompile sorted them out, or worst case scenario, importing to a new db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `If Not ComboBox1.Text = "" Then` to `If Not ComboBox1 = "" Then`

For whatever reason Access does not like you use the `.Text` property outside of it's strict control.

Comment: You can use text when a control has the focus, and as this is the change event for the control, it has the focus.

Comment: I thought `change might be able to have it fire if you changed the text/record programmatically but I guess not!